# 'App Service Logs' option missing from Azure App

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics

I am intending to enable logging in my Azure app. I am following the instructions by Microsoft on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs), where they state to go to my app and select `App service logs`, but I see no such option for my app. [This](https://ardalis.com/configuring-logging-in-azure-app-services/) resource has the same instruction but I don't have that option. I am running on the Basic configuration for the app (the cheapest option), could that be the issue?

This is all I have under Monitoring (see image below)

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Also, the `Logs` option is completely different it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had to upgrade to a minimum of `Standard tier` configuration to get the option to set up App Service Logs. It is Unfortunately about triple the cost of the `Basic` tier.

Answer (score 1):

Which region are you running your app service on?

I just tried with `Basic(B1)` app service and I was able to configure `app service logs`

[image]

Comment: My app is in a specific region in Au. Eastern Australia I believe.

Comment: Would you please be able to also show a screenshot of your config, AKA your tier, to show that you are indeed on Basic

Comment: It is in the screenshot above. I have edited it to highlight the SKU

Comment: Mhh, that is interesting. I guess I will have to request Microsoft support on this one before I know what the reason is. Cheers

Comment: What subscription do you use? In the past I have had similar issues with subscriptions stamped out from a CSP. It may or may not apply to you, but worth exploring that angle